# Downloading CSV File from Web in Haskell

Tags: csv, haskell

Please i have the code below in a folder H1.hs

```
    Module H1 Where
    Import System.IO
    Import Network.HTTP
    Import Network.URI
    Import Data.Maybe

    downloadCSV :: String -> IO (Bool, String)
    downloadCSV mDa = do
let mu = "http://xxx.xxx.xx/aaa.s.csv?s=" mu
let mh = simpleHTTP $ getRequest mu
mr <- (mh >>= getResponseBody)
rc <- fmap rpc <$> mh
case rc of 
left err -> return (False, "xxxx" show err)
right(2,_,_) -> return (True, mr)
```

My question is I want to create another file  H2.hs and call the function in H1.hs(downloadCSV)
from my main method so that the csv file can be downloaded.
ex:

```
main do = ........
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

File `H2.hs` will look like this:

```
module H2 where
import H1 (downloadCSV)

main = do ...
          (bool,str) <- downloadCSV "some-url"
          ...
```